# Localization of Python, UTF coding

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8

I am running my program on python.

But when trying to change language coding, when I used `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-.` code I received the error listed below

```
[zeybek16@ssh ~]$ python ex1.py
  File "ex1.py", line 1
SyntaxError: encoding problem: with BOM
```

Comment: check the spelling of your title and yor question (Py*th*on, U*TF*) :) good luck

Comment: Are you **certain** you spelled `coding: utf-8` correctly? It appears your editor has saved the file with an [UTF-8 byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), but the `coding` header found did not match `utf-8`.